# check availability record code not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel

I need your help with below code. The below code suppose in case the user don't have any record in the Orders table to show him the UsOrderpanel and UsOrderlbl a message, and if he already have then it will show to him Usorderspan but in fact the code whatever if the user has orders In Orders table or not it show to him Usorderspan  which this panel should be only shown when user has record

```
protected void MyordersLinkBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (Session["UsrNme"] != null)
        {
            using (SqlConnection UsOrderCon = new SqlConnection(sc))
            {
                UsOrderCon.Open();
                string chksUsOrderstring = "Select count (*) from Orders where UID=@chkUID";
                SqlCommand ChkUsOrderCMD = new SqlCommand(chksUsOrderstring, UsOrderCon);
                ChkUsOrderCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@chkUID", Payexictlbl.Text);
                //Check if orderId exists in db and if not then show the message
                if (!(Convert.ToInt32(ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar()) > 0))
                {

                    Usorderspan.Visible = true;
                    UsOrderpanel.Visible = false;
                    SqlDataAdapter UsOrderADPA = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT [OrderNo], [UID], [SubDate], [EndSubDate], [Amount], [Product], [payntmeth] FROM [Orders] WHERE  [UID] = @uSer ", sc);
                    var Userss = Session["UsrNme"];
                    UsOrderADPA.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uSer", Userss);
                    DataSet UsOrderDST = new DataSet();

                    UsOrderADPA.Fill(UsOrderDST);

                    UsrOrdersCompLstViw.DataSource = UsOrderDST.Tables[0];
                    UsrOrdersCompLstViw.DataBind();

                }

                else
                {
                    UsOrderpanel.Visible = true;
                    UsOrderlbl.Text = "You dont have any orders";
                }
            }

        }
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 8;

    }

    }
```

Comment: !(Convert.ToInt32(ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar()) > 0) is pretty much equivalent to Convert.ToInt32(ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar()) == 0 since you cannot have a negative count.

Comment: Did you put some breakpoints in there? Does the code execute? What does ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar() return?

Comment: Hi @Mihai Caracostea yes sure i have put breakpoints and the code dont continue to else part since the user dont have any orders

Comment: @Mihai Caracostea   i have also use Convert.ToInt32(ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar()) == 0 as you mention but it still showing the Usorderspan even the user dont have any order in the table

Answer (score 0):

Reading your question better, I think you got your condition the other way around. You say that if he does NOT have records in Orders, you want to show him UsOrderpanel and UsOrderlbl. And if he has, show him Usorderspan.

Looking at your code, you do it opposite: if he does NOT have records in Orders, you do

```
Usorderspan.Visible = true;
UsOrderpanel.Visible = false;
...
```

And if he has records you do

```
UsOrderpanel.Visible = true;
UsOrderlbl.Text = "You dont have any orders";
```

You should change you condition to

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(ChkUsOrderCMD.ExecuteScalar()) > 0)
```

Comment: Hi @Mihai Caracostea, many thanks for your reply i have did exactly as i mention in your answer but really nothing happen the user dont have any record and still the code did not pass to else statement at all it suppose the UsOrderpanel appear but that not happening the  Usorderspan it shown without any record